# Hue cannot connect, error on connection refused, HBase cannot choose master, hdfs stopped working

Tags: hbase, hdfs, cloudera, webhdfs

THIS QUESTION WILL BE ANSWERED BY MYSELF
Problem:  I cannot access HBase, the infamous znode == null stack trace is given when calling a command from Hbase shell (all this on Cloudera quickstart CDH 5.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps taken to solve this problem (over 12 h of research):

1. Going to Hue, notice that the a "`config mismatch error`" plus some other dead service (Hive, Impala, Oozie)
2. The port to which Hue tries to connect is 50070
3. Zookeeper gives an error stating that connection was refused when electing Master (from /var/log/zookeeper)
4. Hbase gives almost the same error as above (/var/log/hbase/.....quickstart.out the most recent one is the one without a number)
5. Data Browser also doesn't work (connection refused on port 9000)
6. trying to see what ports are open to listen, the 50070 port is missing
7. Cloudera states that it's the port used by the namenode of HDFS and the configuration files (/etc/conf/hdfs...) confirm it
8. The hdfs.namenode.out log in /var/log/hdfs show that FSImage cannot be read
9. ***SOLUTION*** Following the path given by the log, there are 3  numered FSImage. I deleted the last one, restarted the machine (from internal shutdown, not closing the window!) and the hdfs rewrited the last one from the second to last and the edit files
10. everything worked fine again.

Hope this helps! Cloudera support takes about 2 days to answer.